# any way to detect the Antivirus installed on a windows server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, wmi, windows-server-2003, antivirus

I want to find what antivirus in installed on the server.

There are four approaches that I have come across till now.

1. There is WMI. But the root/securityCenter and root/securityCenter2 namespaces are not available on the server editions of windows.
   [Detect Antivirus on Windows using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331887/detect-antivirus-on-windows-using-c-sharp)
2. Perform a dictionary search after getting the list of the currently installed softwares as it is mentioned here by Leonardo.
   [How to detect antivirus on Windows Server 2008 in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732351/how-to-detect-antivirus-on-windows-server-2008-in-c)
3. Using the OESIS framework for doing it. The problem with it is that it is licensed. I am looking for an open source framework.
4. Using the EICAR test file and seeing that the antivirus detects it or not. That would not be a good option for me.

Is there any way I can get the information other than performing a dictionary search.

Comment: Why are you wanting to detect AV on a server?

Comment: @Dai..because the monitoring by the antivirus has performance issues with my application