# How can I detect if a firewall product is enabled?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api

How can I detect (from a Windows Forms application written in C#) if a firewall product is enabled?

Here is my code and i am getting error on **INetFwMgr that type or namespace could not found**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private const string CLSID_FIREWALL_MANAGER = "{304CE942-6E39-40D8-943A-B913C40C9CD4}"; 

       INetFwMgr manager = GetFireWallManager();
       bool isFirewallEnabled = manager.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.FirewallEnabled;



       private static INetFwMgr GetFireWallManager()
       {
           Type objectType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid(CLSID_FIREWALL_MANAGER));
           return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType) as INetFwMgr;
       }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            if (isFirewallEnabled == false)
           {
                MessageBox.Show("Firewall is not enabled.");
           }
           else
           {
                MessageBox.Show("Firewall is enabled.");
           }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [**Check for Third Party Firewalls on a Machine**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615203/check-for-third-party-firewalls-on-a-machine) [**Check if external firewall is enabled?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975321/c-sharp-how-to-chceck-if-external-firewall-is-enabled) [Controlling Windows firewall via COM Interop](http://www.shafqatahmed.com/2008/01/controlling-win.html) [Automating Windows Firewall Settings with C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/08/21/automating-windows-firewall-settings-with-c.aspx) [Detect if windows firewall is blocking my program](http:

Comment: Are you missing a using directive?

Comment: Yes. How To Solve This ?

Comment: Add the namespace Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common to your code.  See the addition in my answer.

Comment: There is nothing dll like Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common but instead there is Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client....i have added this namespance but still it is showing the same error...i am doing my app in Framwork 2.0

Comment: Runtime version for this assembly is v2.0.50727. If you cannot find it in the 'Reference Assemblies\v2.0' folder in your installation folder of Visual Studio, you will have to download the dll and add it to your GAC (Global Assembly Cache).

Comment: Thnx..I have solved I have changed Version of Framework to 4.0 ....It Works..

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a old post but I found a great solution!
Read the registry key of firewall status found in:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile
> Key: EnableFirewall

```
public static bool isFirewallEnabled() {
        try {
            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\SharedAccess\\Parameters\\FirewallPolicy\\StandardProfile")) {
                if (key == null) {
                    return false;
                } else { 
                    Object o = key.GetValue("EnableFirewall");
                    if (o == null) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        int firewall = (int)o;
                        if (firewall == 1) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Also you can get values for DomainProfile, PublicProfile and StandardProfile. You can get FirewallRules too.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

```
NetFwMgrType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr", false); 
INetFwMgr mgr = (INetFwMgr)Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType);
bool Firewallenabled = mgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.FirewallEnabled;
```

For details see a link.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737845%28WS.10%29.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/08/21/automating-windows-firewall-settings-with-c.aspx

Comment: See answer by Jeetendra negi below on how to get this code to compile.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this question here about antivirus [How to detect antivirus installed on windows 2003 server and 2008 server 2003 server R2and 2008 server R2 using WMI or other then WMI in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396757/how-to-detect-antivirus-installed-on-windows-2003-server-and-2008-server-2003-se) the same API call can be used to detect firewall settings using the [`WSC_SECURITY_PROVIDER_FIREWALL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) enum. The answer there is actually wrong for that question, but it will give you the answer for non-server computers.  That code is in C++, but it's just the windows API call you need, you can call that from C# too.

Comment: Note that this will only detect locally running firewall applications.  It won't (and can't) detect firewall appliances and the like.

Comment: No it won't but given the tags on this question (windows-firewall, etc.) I assumed the OP meant local firewall

Comment: Probably, I was just trying to be complete.

Comment: I just want to check in local machine when i click on button in ny window form it checks the code for firewall status so can u help how to write code fore this ?

Comment: @PavanAnadkat Can you clarify, do you want to check if a computer on the internet can connect to a port on the computer, or just if the local computer has firewall running or not? Those are two very different issues with different solutions.

Comment: I just want to check on local computer that firewall is on or off ? I have added my code and i am getting error on INetFwMgr

Comment: @PavanAnadkat You may want to roll back your changes, mark a answer as accepted and ask a new question (and include a link to the answer you used here) with what you did and a explanation of what error you are getting as most of these answers are for how to get to INetFwMgr, not how to debug its use.

Answer (score 1):

You'll first need to add the following component to your project

- **INetFwMgr**

Then, get the object type from the Home Networking Configuration Manager CLSID which is `{304CE942-6E39-40D8-943A-B913C40C9CD4}`(Links to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll` and can be found at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{304CE942-6E39-40D8-943A-B913C40C9CD4}`) and use the type gathered to create an instance using the type's default constructor as a new `INetFwMgr` which will be used to detect whether the firewall is enabled or not using `INetFwMgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.FirewallEnabled` which returns a `bool`

```
private const string CLSID_FIREWALL_MANAGER = "{304CE942-6E39-40D8-943A-B913C40C9CD4}"; //This is the CLSID of Home Networking Configuration Manager. We'll use this to detect whether the Firewall is enabled or not
private static NetFwTypeLib.INetFwMgr GetHNCMType()
{
    Type objectType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid(CLSID_FIREWALL_MANAGER)); //Creates a new GUID from CLSID_FIREWALL_MANAGER getting its type as objectType
    return Activator.CreateInstance(objectType) as NetFwTypeLib.INetFwMgr; //Creates an instance from the object type we gathered as an INetFwMgr object
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    INetFwMgr manager = GetHNCMType(); //Initializes a new INetFwMgr of name manager from GetHNCMType
    if (manager.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.FirewallEnabled == false) //Continue if the firewall is not enabled
    {
        //The firewall is not enabled
        Console.WriteLine("OFF"); //Writes OFF to the Console in a new line
    }
    else //Otherwise:
    {
        //The fire wall is enabled
        Console.WriteLine("ON"); //Writes ON to the Console in a new line
    }
}
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

---

To add a component to your project,

- Right-click **References** from the **Solution Explorer** under your
  project name and select **Add Reference...**
- Under the tab **COM**, select the component you'd like to add and click on **OK**

Comment: i did not find INetFwMgr Under COM. Now How can i add this component ?

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'INetFwMgr' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\users\administrator.mustuspune\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 
I am getting this error

Answer (score 1):

just import the refrences from C://windows/system32/hnetcfg.dll and C://windows/system32/FirewallAPI.dll

then use

```
using NATUPNPLib;
using NETCONLib;
using NetFwTypeLib;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [FwMgr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365287%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for old Windows versions (XP) and use [Windows Firewall with Advanced Security API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff956124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Vista and Above.

Here is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that retrieves the firewall setting.